# second derivative of an implicit system of equations

Tags: implicit-differentiation

The system of equations:

$x-u^2-v^2+9=0$

$y-u^2+v^2-10=0$

defines $(u,v)$ as a function of $(x,y)$ in every point $u\cdot v\ne 0$

I wish to find $u_{xx}$

I managed to find $u_x$:

if $F=(x-u^2-v^2+9,y-u^2+v^2-10)$ than $u_x=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\frac{1}{4u}$

but i have no idea how to find the second derivative.

any ideas? (the answer is $-\frac{1}{16u^3}$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well
$$
u_{xx}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}u_x=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{1}{4u}=-\frac{1}{4u^2}u_x=-\frac{1}{16u^3}
$$

Comment: thanks, I thought it will be much more complex...